# Table of OIDs for certificate's subject?

Tags: certificate, x509, asn.1, oid, dn

Is there any table where we can find all correspondences between OIDs and attributes they represent in the subject field of certificate. For example, I know that "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2" means certificate's template name, "2.5.29.30" - name restrictions. Where can we find other oids especially for main attributes such as CN, C, S, L, O, OU...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Certificate subject X.509](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464129/certificate-subject-x-509)

Comment: You can find *many* of the OIDs for the X.520 attributes in [X.520 : Information technology - Open Systems Interconnection - The Directory: Selected attribute types](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.520). Its not a complete list because those things are scattered everywhere. You will probably never find a list with *all* of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772812(WS.10).aspx

Comment: As is common, this link-only answer seems to have rotted.

Comment: Found a copy on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20150107151622/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772812(WS.10).aspx

Comment: @NickT Actually, at this day (28/12/2019) the link works.

Comment: Still working as of March 2023...

Answer (score 5):

A very good reference is Peter Gutmann's dumpasn1 tool. It has an extensive [configuration file](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/dumpasn1.cfg) which is a database for many PKI related OIDs.

Alternatively OpenSSL's database of OID isn't human readable in its [original](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/objects/objects.txt) or [processed](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/objects/obj_dat.h). But using OpenSSL functions like `OBJ_nid2obj` or `OBJ_obj2nid` in combination with `BJ_nid2ln` and `OBJ_nid2sn` you can easily make lookups.

Answer (score 3):

More...

```
    '2.16.840.1.113730.3' => 'directory',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.4.1' => 'serverGatedCrypto',
    '2.16.840.1.113733.1.6.3' => 'Unknown Verisign extension',
    '2.16.840.1.113733.1.6.6' => 'Unknown Verisign extension',
    '2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.1.1' => 'Verisign certificatePolicy',
    '2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.1.1.1' => 'Unknown Verisign policy qualifier',
    '2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.1.1.2' => 'Unknown Verisign policy qualifier',
    '2.23.133' => 'TCPA',
    '2.23.133.1' => 'tcpa_specVersion',
    '2.23.133.2' => 'tcpa_attribute',
    '2.23.133.2.1' => 'tcpa_at_tpmManufacturer',
    '2.23.133.2.10' => 'tcpa_at_securityQualities',
    '2.23.133.2.11' => 'tcpa_at_tpmProtectionProfile',
    '2.23.133.2.12' => 'tcpa_at_tpmSecurityTarget',
    '2.23.133.2.13' => 'tcpa_at_foundationProtectionProfile',
    '2.23.133.2.14' => 'tcpa_at_foundationSecurityTarget',
    '2.23.133.2.15' => 'tcpa_at_tpmIdLabel',
    '2.23.133.2.2' => 'tcpa_at_tpmModel',
    '2.23.133.2.3' => 'tcpa_at_tpmVersion',
    '2.23.133.2.4' => 'tcpa_at_platformManufacturer',
    '2.23.133.2.5' => 'tcpa_at_platformModel',
    '2.23.133.2.6' => 'tcpa_at_platformVersion',
    '2.23.133.2.7' => 'tcpa_at_componentManufacturer',
    '2.23.133.2.8' => 'tcpa_at_componentModel',
    '2.23.133.2.9' => 'tcpa_at_componentVersion',
    '2.23.133.3' => 'tcpa_protocol',
    '2.23.133.3.1' => 'tcpa_prtt_tpmIdProtocol',
    '2.23.42.0' => 'contentType',
    '2.23.42.0.0' => 'PANData',
    '2.23.42.0.1' => 'PANToken',
    '2.23.42.0.2' => 'PANOnly',
    '2.23.42.1' => 'msgExt',
    '2.23.42.10' => 'national',
    '2.23.42.10.192' => 'Japan',
    '2.23.42.2' => 'field',
    '2.23.42.2.0' => 'fullName',
    '2.23.42.2.1' => 'givenName',
    '2.23.42.2.10' => 'amount',
    '2.23.42.2.2' => 'familyName',
    '2.23.42.2.3' => 'birthFamilyName',
    '2.23.42.2.4' => 'placeName',
    '2.23.42.2.5' => 'identificationNumber',
    '2.23.42.2.6' => 'month',
    '2.23.42.2.7' => 'date',
    '2.23.42.2.7.11' => 'accountNumber',
    '2.23.42.2.7.12' => 'passPhrase',
    '2.23.42.2.8' => 'address',
    '2.23.42.2.9' => 'telephone',
    '2.23.42.3' => 'attribute',
    '2.23.42.3.0' => 'cert',
    '2.23.42.3.0.0' => 'rootKeyThumb',
    '2.23.42.3.0.1' => 'additionalPolicy',
    '2.23.42.4' => 'algorithm',
    '2.23.42.5' => 'policy',
    '2.23.42.5.0' => 'root',
    '2.23.42.6' => 'module',
    '2.23.42.7' => 'certExt',
    '2.23.42.7.0' => 'hashedRootKey',
    '2.23.42.7.1' => 'certificateType',
    '2.23.42.7.2' => 'merchantData',
    '2.23.42.7.3' => 'cardCertRequired',
    '2.23.42.7.4' => 'tunneling',
    '2.23.42.7.5' => 'setExtensions',
    '2.23.42.7.6' => 'setQualifier',
    '2.23.42.8' => 'brand',
    '2.23.42.8.1' => 'IATA-ATA',
    '2.23.42.8.30' => 'Diners',
    '2.23.42.8.34' => 'AmericanExpress',
    '2.23.42.8.4' => 'VISA',
    '2.23.42.8.5' => 'MasterCard',
    '2.23.42.8.6011' => 'Novus',
    '2.23.42.9' => 'vendor',
    '2.23.42.9.0' => 'GlobeSet',
    '2.23.42.9.1' => 'IBM',
    '2.23.42.9.10' => 'Griffin',
    '2.23.42.9.11' => 'Certicom',
    '2.23.42.9.12' => 'OSS',
    '2.23.42.9.13' => 'TenthMountain',
    '2.23.42.9.14' => 'Antares',
    '2.23.42.9.15' => 'ECC',
    '2.23.42.9.16' => 'Maithean',
    '2.23.42.9.17' => 'Netscape',
    '2.23.42.9.18' => 'Verisign',
    '2.23.42.9.19' => 'BlueMoney',
    '2.23.42.9.2' => 'CyberCash',
    '2.23.42.9.20' => 'Lacerte',
    '2.23.42.9.21' => 'Fujitsu',
    '2.23.42.9.22' => 'eLab',
    '2.23.42.9.23' => 'Entrust',
    '2.23.42.9.24' => 'VIAnet',
    '2.23.42.9.25' => 'III',
    '2.23.42.9.26' => 'OpenMarket',
    '2.23.42.9.27' => 'Lexem',
    '2.23.42.9.28' => 'Intertrader',
    '2.23.42.9.29' => 'Persimmon',
    '2.23.42.9.3' => 'Terisa',
    '2.23.42.9.30' => 'NABLE',
    '2.23.42.9.31' => 'espace-net',
    '2.23.42.9.32' => 'Hitachi',
    '2.23.42.9.33' => 'Microsoft',
    '2.23.42.9.34' => 'NEC',
    '2.23.42.9.35' => 'Mitsubishi',
    '2.23.42.9.36' => 'NCR',
    '2.23.42.9.37' => 'e-COMM',
    '2.23.42.9.38' => 'Gemplus',
    '2.23.42.9.4' => 'RSADSI',
    '2.23.42.9.5' => 'VeriFone',
    '2.23.42.9.6' => 'TrinTech',
    '2.23.42.9.7' => 'BankGate',
    '2.23.42.9.8' => 'GTE',
    '2.23.42.9.9' => 'CompuSource',
    '2.5.29.1' => 'authorityKeyIdentifier',
    '2.5.29.10' => 'basicConstraints',
    '2.5.29.11' => 'nameConstraints',
    '2.5.29.12' => 'policyConstraints',
    '2.5.29.13' => 'basicConstraints',
    '2.5.29.14' => 'subjectKeyIdentifier',
    '2.5.29.15' => 'keyUsage',
    '2.5.29.16' => 'privateKeyUsagePeriod',
    '2.5.29.17' => 'subjectAltName',
    '2.5.29.18' => 'issuerAltName',
    '2.5.29.19' => 'basicConstraints',
    '2.5.29.2' => 'keyAttributes',
    '2.5.29.20' => 'cRLNumber',
    '2.5.29.21' => 'cRLReason',
    '2.5.29.22' => 'expirationDate',
    '2.5.29.23' => 'instructionCode',
    '2.5.29.24' => 'invalidityDate',
    '2.5.29.26' => 'issuingDistributionPoint',
    '2.5.29.27' => 'deltaCRLIndicator',
    '2.5.29.28' => 'issuingDistributionPoint',
    '2.5.29.29' => 'certificateIssuer',
    '2.5.29.3' => 'certificatePolicies',
    '2.5.29.30' => 'nameConstraints',
    '2.5.29.31' => 'cRLDistributionPoints',
    '2.5.29.32' => 'certificatePolicies',
    '2.5.29.33' => 'policyMappings',
    '2.5.29.34' => 'policyConstraints',
    '2.5.29.35' => 'authorityKeyIdentifier',
    '2.5.29.36' => 'policyConstraints',
    '2.5.29.37' => 'extKeyUsage',
    '2.5.29.4' => 'keyUsageRestriction',
    '2.5.29.5' => 'policyMapping',
    '2.5.29.6' => 'subtreesConstraint',
    '2.5.29.7' => 'subjectAltName',
    '2.5.29.8' => 'issuerAltName',
    '2.5.29.9' => 'subjectDirectoryAttributes',
    '2.5.4.0' => 'objectClass',
    '2.5.4.1' => 'aliasObjectName',
    '2.5.4.12' => 'title',
    '2.5.4.13' => 'description',
    '2.5.4.14' => 'searchGuide',
    '2.5.4.15' => 'businessCategory',
    '2.5.4.16' => 'postalAddress',
    '2.5.4.17' => 'postalCode',
    '2.5.4.18' => 'postOfficeBox',
    '2.5.4.19' => 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName',
    '2.5.4.2' => 'knowledgeInformation',
    '2.5.4.20' => 'telephoneNumber',
    '2.5.4.21' => 'telexNumber',
    '2.5.4.22' => 'teletexTerminalIdentifier',
    '2.5.4.23' => 'facsimileTelephoneNumber',
    '2.5.4.24' => 'x121Address',
    '2.5.4.25' => 'internationalISDNNumber',
    '2.5.4.26' => 'registeredAddress',
    '2.5.4.27' => 'destinationIndicator',
    '2.5.4.28' => 'preferredDeliveryMehtod',
    '2.5.4.29' => 'presentationAddress',
    '2.5.4.30' => 'supportedApplicationContext',
    '2.5.4.31' => 'member',
    '2.5.4.32' => 'owner',
    '2.5.4.33' => 'roleOccupant',
    '2.5.4.34' => 'seeAlso',
    '2.5.4.35' => 'userPassword',
    '2.5.4.36' => 'userCertificate',
    '2.5.4.37' => 'caCertificate',
    '2.5.4.38' => 'authorityRevocationList',
    '2.5.4.39' => 'certificateRevocationList',
    '2.5.4.40' => 'crossCertificatePair',
    '2.5.4.41' => 'givenName',
    '2.5.4.42' => 'givenName',
    '2.5.4.5' => 'serialNumber',
    '2.5.4.52' => 'supportedAlgorithms',
    '2.5.4.53' => 'deltaRevocationList',
    '2.5.4.58' => 'crossCertificatePair',
    '2.5.4.9' => 'streetAddress',
    '2.5.8' => 'X.500-Algorithms',
    '2.5.8.1' => 'X.500-Alg-Encryption',
    '2.5.8.1.1' => 'rsa',
    '2.16.76.1.1' => 'DPC',
    '2.16.76.1.1.0' => 'DPC da AC Raiz',
    '2.16.76.1.1.1' => 'DPC da AC Presidência',
    '2.16.76.1.1.2' => 'DPC da AC Serpro',
    '2.16.76.1.1.3' => 'DPC da SERASA Autoridade Certificadora Principal - ACP',
    '2.16.76.1.1.4' => 'DPC da SERASA Autoridade Certificadora - AC',
    '2.16.76.1.1.5' => 'DPC da AC CertiSign na ICP­Brasil',
    '2.16.76.1.1.6' => 'DPC da AC CertiSign SPB na ICP­Brasil',
    '2.16.76.1.1.7' => 'DPC da SERASA Certificadora Digital',
    '2.16.76.1.1.8' => 'DPC da AC SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.1.9' => 'DPC da AC CAIXA',
    '2.16.76.1.1.10' => 'DPC da AC CAIXA IN',
    '2.16.76.1.1.11' => 'DPC da AC CAIXA PJ',
    '2.16.76.1.1.12' => 'DPC da AC CAIXA PF',
    '2.16.76.1.1.13' => 'DPC da AC SERPRO SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.1.14' => 'DPC da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla',
    '2.16.76.1.1.15' => 'DPC da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para Secretaria da Receita Federal',
    '2.16.76.1.1.16' => 'DPC da AC SERASA SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.1.17' => 'DPC da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.1.18' => 'DPC da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE',
    '2.16.76.1.1.19' => 'DPC da Autoridade Certificadora do Sistema Justiça Federal - AC­JUS',
    '2.16.76.1.1.20' => 'Declaração de Práticas de Certificação da Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO Final - DPC SERPRO ACF',
    '2.16.76.1.1' => 'DPC',
    '2.16.76.1.1.21' => 'Declaração de Práticas de Certificação da Autoridade Certificadora SINCOR',
    '2.16.76.1.1.22' => 'Declaração de Práticas de Certificação da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial SP SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.1.23' => 'Declaração de Práticas de Certificação da AC FENACOR',
    '2.16.76.1.1.24' => 'Declaração de Práticas de Certificação da Autoridade Certificadora SERPRO­ JUS',
    '2.16.76.1.1.25' => 'DPC da AC Caixa Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.1.26' => 'DPC da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial SP (AC IMESP)',
    '2.16.76.1.1.27' => 'DPC da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.1.28' => 'Declaração de Práticas de Certificação da Autoridade Certificadora CertSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.1.29' => 'DPC da AC SERASA JUS',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1' => 'A1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.1' => 'Política de Certificados da ACSERPRO para certificados SERPRO­SPB ­ PC SERPRO­SPB',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.2' => 'Política de Certificados para certificados da SERASA Autoridade Certificadora',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.3' => 'Política de Certificados da Autoridade Certificadora da Presidência da República - PCA1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.4' => 'Política de Certificado da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Certificadora Digital para o Sistema de Pagamentos Brasileiro  na ICP­Brasil­ PC da AC CertiSign SPB na ICP­Brasil',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.5' => 'Política de Certificados SEPROA1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.6' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 - SERASA CD',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.7' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A1 da AC Caixa IN',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.8' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A1 da AC Caixa PF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.9' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A1 da AC Caixa PJ',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.10' => 'Política de Certificados da Autoridade Certificadora do Serpro­SRF para certificados de assinatura digital do tipo A1 (PCSerpro­SRFA1)',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.11' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla na Infra­estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.12' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Secretaria da Receita Federal',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.13' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da AC SERASA SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.14' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.15' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.16' => 'Política de Certificados SERPRO do Tipo A1 - PC SERPRO ACF A1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.17' => 'Política de Certificados do SERPRO - SPB - PC SERPRO ACF SPB',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.18' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora SINCOR',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.19' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora SINCOR para Corretores de Seguros',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1' => 'A1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.20' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial SP SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.21' => 'Política de Certificados SERPRO­JUS do tipo A1 ­ PCSERPROJUSA1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.22' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A1 da AC Caixa Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.23' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.24' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A1 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.25' => 'Política de Certificado Digital da AC SERASA­JUS para Certificados Tipo A1',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2' => 'A2',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2.1' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A2 - SERASA CD',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2.2' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A2 da AC SERASA SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2.3' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A2 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign últipla na Infra­estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2.4' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A2 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2.5' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A2 da AC Caixa Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2.6' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A2 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.2.7' => 'Política de Certificado Digital da AC SERASA­JUS para Certificados Tipo A2',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3' => 'A3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.1' => 'Política de Certificados da Autoridade Certificadora da Presidência da República - PC ACPR',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.2' => 'Política de Certificados da Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO para certificados SERPRO do tipo A3 - PCSERPROA3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.3' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A3 - SERASA CD',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.4' => 'Política de Certificados da Autoridade Certificadora do Serpro­SRF para certificados de assinatura digital do tipo A3 (PCSerpro­SRFA3)',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.5' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla na Infra­estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.6' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Secretaria da Receita Federal na Infra­estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.7' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da AC Caixa IN',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.8' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da AC Caixa PF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.9' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da AC Caixa PJ',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.10' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da AC SERASA SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.11' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.12' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.13' => 'Política de Certificados SERPRO do Tipo A3 - PC SERPRO A3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.14' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora SINCOR',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.15' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora SINCOR para Corretores de Seguros',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.16' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial SP SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3' => 'A3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.17' => 'Política de Certificado da AC FENACOR A3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.18' => 'Política de Certificados SERPRO­JUS do tipo A3 PCSERPROJUSA3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.19' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A3 da AC Caixa Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.20' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.21' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A3 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3.22' => 'Política de Certificado Digital da AC SERASA­JUS para Certificados Tipo A3',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4' => 'A4',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.1' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A4 - SERASA CD;',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.2' => 'VAGO',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.3' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo A4 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla na Infra­estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.4' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A4  da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Secretaria da Receita Federal na Infra­estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.5' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A4 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.6' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A4 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial - SP SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.7' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Tipo A4 da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.8' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo A4 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.9' => 'VAGO',
    '2.16.76.1.2.4.10' => 'Política de Certificado Digital a AC SERASA­JUS para Certificados Tipo A4',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101' => 'S1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101.1' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S1-SERASA CD',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101.2' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S1 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101.3' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo do Tipo S1 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101.4' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo do Tipo S1 da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101.5' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo S1 da AC Caixa Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101.6' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo S1 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.101.7' => 'Política de Certificado Digital da AC SERASA­JUS para Cerficados Tipo S1',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.102' => 'S2',
    '2.16.76.1.2.102.1' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S2 - SERASA CD',
    '2.16.76.1.2.102.2' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S2 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.102.3' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo do Tipo S2 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla',
    '2.16.76.1.2.102.4' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo S2 da AC Caixa Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.102.5' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo S2 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.102.6' => 'Política de Certificado Digital da AC SERASA­JUS para Certificados Tipo S2',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103' => 'S3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.1' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S3 - SERASA CD',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.2' => 'VAGO',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.3' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo do Tipo S3 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.4' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S3 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.5' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S3 da Autoridade Certificadora PRODEMGE',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.6' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital do Tipo S3 da AC Caixa Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.7' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo S3 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.103.8' => 'Política de Certificado Digital da AC SERASA­JUS para Certificados Tipo S3',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.104' => 'S4',
    '2.16.76.1.2.104.1' => 'Política de Certificado Digital para Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S4 - SERASA CD',
    '2.16.76.1.2.104.2' => 'VAGO',
    '2.16.76.1.2.104.3' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo do Tipo S4 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign Múltipla',
    '2.16.76.1.2.104.4' => 'Política de Certificado de Sigilo Tipo S4 da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial ­ SP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.104.5' => 'Política de Certificado de Assinatura Digital Tipo S4 da Autoridade Certificadora CertiSign para a Justiça',
    '2.16.76.1.2.104.6' => 'Política de Certificado Digital da AC SERASA­JUS para Certificados Tipo S4',
    '2.16.76.1.2' => 'PC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201' => 'PC de AC',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201.1' => 'PC da Serasa Autoridade Certificadora Principal - ACP',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201.2' => 'PC da AC CertiSign na ICP­Brasil',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201.3' => 'PC da AC SRF',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201.4' => 'Política de Certificados da Autoridade Certificadora Caixa',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201.5' => 'PC da Autoridade Certificadora do Sistema Justiça Federal - AC­ JUS',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201.6' => 'PC da Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO (AC SERPRO)',
    '2.16.76.1.2.201.7' => 'PC da Autoridade Certificadora Imprensa Oficial SP (AC IMESP)',
    '2.16.76.1.3' => 'Atributos Obrigatórios de Certificados',
    '2.16.76.1.3.1' => 'campo otherName em certificado de pessoa física',
    '2.16.76.1.3.2' => 'campo otherName em certificado de pessoa jurídica',
    '2.16.76.1.3.3' => 'campo otherName em certificado de pessoa jurídica',
    '2.16.76.1.3.4' => 'campo otherName em certificado de pessoa jurídica',
    '2.16.76.1.3.5' => 'campo otherName em certificado de pessoa física',
    '2.16.76.1.3.6' => 'campo otherName em certificado de pessoa física',
    '2.16.76.1.3.7' => 'campo otherName em certificado de pessoa jurídica',
    '2.16.76.1.4' => 'Atributos Opcionais de Certificados',
    '2.16.76.1.4.1' => 'Entidades Sindicais',
    '2.16.76.1.4.1.1' => 'SINCOR',
    '2.16.76.1.4.1.1.1' => 'Número de registro do corretor associado');
```

Answer (score 1):

In nfephp (git) you can find in Certificate class:

```
$oidsTable = array(
    '2.5.4.3' => 'CN',
    '2.5.4.4' => 'Surname',
    '2.5.4.6' => 'C',
    '2.5.4.7' => 'Cidade',
    '2.5.4.8' => 'Estado',
    '2.5.4.9' => 'StreetAddress',
    '2.5.4.10' => 'O',
    '2.5.4.11' => 'OU',
    '2.5.4.12' => 'Title',
    '2.5.4.20' => 'TelephoneNumber',
    '2.5.4.42' => 'GivenName',
    '2.5.29.14' => 'id-ce-subjectKeyIdentifier',
    '2.5.29.15' => 'id-ce-keyUsage',
    '2.5.29.17' => 'id-ce-subjectAltName',
    '2.5.29.19' => 'id-ce-basicConstraints',
    '2.5.29.20' => 'id-ce-cRLNumber',
    '2.5.29.31' => 'id-ce-CRLDistributionPoints',
    '2.5.29.32' => 'id-ce-certificatePolicies',
    '2.5.29.35' => 'id-ce-authorityKeyIdentifier',
    '2.5.29.37' => 'id-ce-extKeyUsage',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.1' => 'Email',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.1' => 'RSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.2' => 'md2WithRSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.4' => 'md5withRSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.5' => 'SHA-1WithRSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.10040.4.3' => 'id-dsa-with-sha-1',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2' => 'id_kp_clientAuth',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4' => 'id_kp_securityemail',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1' => 'id_certificatePolicies',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.1' => 'netscape-cert-type',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.2' => 'netscape-base-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.3' => 'netscape-revocation-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.4' => 'netscape-ca-revocation-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.7' => 'netscape-cert-renewal-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.8' => 'netscape-ca-policy-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.12' => 'netscape-ssl-server-name',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.13' => 'netscape-comment',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1' => 'A1',
    '2.16.76.1.2.3' => 'A3',
    '2.16.76.1.2.1.16' => 'Certification Practice Statement pointer',
    '2.16.76.1.3.1' => 'Dados do cert parte 1',
    '2.16.76.1.3.5' => 'Dados do cert parte 2',
    '2.16.76.1.3.6' => 'Dados do cert parte 3',
    '0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25' => 'domainComponent',
    '1.2.36.68980861.1.1.10' => 'Signet pilot',
    '1.2.36.68980861.1.1.11' => 'Signet intraNet',
    '1.2.36.68980861.1.1.2' => 'Signet personal',
    '1.2.36.68980861.1.1.20' => 'Signet securityPolicy',
    '1.2.36.68980861.1.1.3' => 'Signet business',
    '1.2.36.68980861.1.1.4' => 'Signet legal',
    '1.2.36.75878867.1.100.1.1' => 'Certificates Australia policyIdentifier',
    '1.2.752.34.1' => 'seis-cp',
    '1.2.752.34.1.1' => 'SEIS certificatePolicy-s10',
    '1.2.752.34.2' => 'SEIS pe',
    '1.2.752.34.3' => 'SEIS at',
    '1.2.752.34.3.1' => 'SEIS at-personalIdentifier',
    '1.2.840.10040.2.1' => 'holdinstruction-none',
    '1.2.840.10040.2.2' => 'holdinstruction-callissuer',
    '1.2.840.10040.2.3' => 'holdinstruction-reject',
    '1.2.840.10040.4.1' => 'dsa',
    '1.2.840.10040.4.3' => 'dsaWithSha1',
    '1.2.840.10045.1' => 'fieldType',
    '1.2.840.10045.1.1' => 'prime-field',
    '1.2.840.10045.1.2' => 'characteristic-two-field',
    '1.2.840.10045.1.2.1' => 'ecPublicKey',
    '1.2.840.10045.1.2.3' => 'characteristic-two-basis',
    '1.2.840.10045.1.2.3.1' => 'onBasis',
    '1.2.840.10045.1.2.3.2' => 'tpBasis',
    '1.2.840.10045.1.2.3.3' => 'ppBasis',
    '1.2.840.10045.2' => 'publicKeyType',
    '1.2.840.10045.2.1' => 'ecPublicKey',
    '1.2.840.10046.2.1' => 'dhPublicNumber',
    '1.2.840.113533.7' => 'nsn',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.65' => 'nsn-ce',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.65.0' => 'entrustVersInfo',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.66' => 'nsn-alg',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.66.10' => 'cast5CBC',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.66.11' => 'cast5MAC',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.66.12' => 'pbeWithMD5AndCAST5-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.66.13' => 'passwordBasedMac',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.66.3' => 'cast3CBC',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.67' => 'nsn-oc',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.67.0' => 'entrustUser',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.68' => 'nsn-at',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.68.0' => 'entrustCAInfo',
    '1.2.840.113533.7.68.10' => 'attributeCertificate',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1' => 'pkcs-1',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.1' => 'rsaEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.2' => 'md2withRSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.3' => 'md4withRSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.4' => 'md5withRSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.5' => 'sha1withRSAEncryption',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.1.6' => 'rsaOAEPEncryptionSET',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.11' => 'SMIMEEncryptionKeyPreference',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12' => 'pkcs-12',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1' => 'pkcs-12-PbeIds',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.1' => 'pbeWithSHAAnd128BitRC4',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.2' => 'pbeWithSHAAnd40BitRC4',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3' => 'pbeWithSHAAnd3-KeyTripleDES-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.4' => 'pbeWithSHAAnd2-KeyTripleDES-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.5' => 'pbeWithSHAAnd128BitRC2-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6' => 'pbeWithSHAAnd40BitRC2-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10' => 'pkcs-12Version1',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1' => 'pkcs-12BadIds',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.1' => 'pkcs-12-keyBag',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.2' => 'pkcs-12-pkcs-8ShroudedKeyBag',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.3' => 'pkcs-12-certBag',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.4' => 'pkcs-12-crlBag',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.5' => 'pkcs-12-secretBag',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.6' => 'pkcs-12-safeContentsBag',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.2' => 'pkcs-12-ESPVKID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.2.1' => 'pkcs-12-PKCS8KeyShrouding',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.3' => 'pkcs-12-BagIds',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.3.1' => 'pkcs-12-keyBagId',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.3.2' => 'pkcs-12-certAndCRLBagId',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.3.3' => 'pkcs-12-secretBagId',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.3.4' => 'pkcs-12-safeContentsId',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.3.5' => 'pkcs-12-pkcs-8ShroudedKeyBagId',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.4' => 'pkcs-12-CertBagID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.4.1' => 'pkcs-12-X509CertCRLBagID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.4.2' => 'pkcs-12-SDSICertBagID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5' => 'pkcs-12-OID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1' => 'pkcs-12-PBEID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1.1' => 'pkcs-12-PBEWithSha1And128BitRC4',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1.2' => 'pkcs-12-PBEWithSha1And40BitRC4',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1.3' => 'pkcs-12-PBEWithSha1AndTripleDESCBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1.4' => 'pkcs-12-PBEWithSha1And128BitRC2CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1.5' => 'pkcs-12-PBEWithSha1And40BitRC2CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1.6' => 'pkcs-12-PBEWithSha1AndRC4',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.1.7' => 'pkcs-12-PBEWithSha1AndRC2CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.2' => 'pkcs-12-EnvelopingID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.2.1' => 'pkcs-12-RSAEncryptionWith128BitRC4',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.2.2' => 'pkcs-12-RSAEncryptionWith40BitRC4',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.2.3' => 'pkcs-12-RSAEncryptionWithTripleDES',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.3' => 'pkcs-12-SignatureID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.12.5.3.1' => 'pkcs-12-RSASignatureWithSHA1Digest',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.3' => 'pkcs-3',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.3.1' => 'dhKeyAgreement',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.5' => 'pkcs-5',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.5.1' => 'pbeWithMD2AndDES-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.5.10' => 'pbeWithSHAAndDES-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.5.3' => 'pbeWithMD5AndDES-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.5.4' => 'pbeWithMD2AndRC2-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.5.6' => 'pbeWithMD5AndRC2-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.5.9' => 'pbeWithMD5AndXOR',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7' => 'pkcs-7',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.1' => 'data',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.2' => 'signedData',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.3' => 'envelopedData',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.4' => 'signedAndEnvelopedData',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.5' => 'digestData',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.6' => 'encryptedData',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.7' => 'dataWithAttributes',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.7.8' => 'encryptedPrivateKeyInfo',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9' => 'pkcs-9',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.1' => 'emailAddress',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.10' => 'issuerAndSerialNumber',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.11' => 'passwordCheck',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.12' => 'publicKey',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.13' => 'signingDescription',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.14' => 'extensionReq',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.15' => 'sMIMECapabilities',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.15.1' => 'preferSignedData',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.15.2' => 'canNotDecryptAny',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.15.3' => 'receiptRequest',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.15.4' => 'receipt',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.15.5' => 'contentHints',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.15.6' => 'mlExpansionHistory',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16' => 'id-sMIME',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.0' => 'id-mod',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.0.1' => 'id-mod-cms',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.0.2' => 'id-mod-ess',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.1' => 'id-ct',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.1.1' => 'id-ct-receipt',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2' => 'id-aa',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.1' => 'id-aa-receiptRequest',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.2' => 'id-aa-securityLabel',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.3' => 'id-aa-mlExpandHistory',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.4' => 'id-aa-contentHint',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.2' => 'unstructuredName',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.20' => 'friendlyName',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.21' => 'localKeyID',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.22' => 'certTypes',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.22.1' => 'x509Certificate',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.22.2' => 'sdsiCertificate',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.23' => 'crlTypes',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.23.1' => 'x509Crl',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.3' => 'contentType',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.4' => 'messageDigest',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.5' => 'signingTime',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.6' => 'countersignature',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.7' => 'challengePassword',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.8' => 'unstructuredAddress',
    '1.2.840.113549.1.9.9' => 'extendedCertificateAttributes',
    '1.2.840.113549.2' => 'digestAlgorithm',
    '1.2.840.113549.2.2' => 'md2',
    '1.2.840.113549.2.4' => 'md4',
    '1.2.840.113549.2.5' => 'md5',
    '1.2.840.113549.3' => 'encryptionAlgorithm',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.10' => 'desCDMF',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.2' => 'rc2CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.3' => 'rc2ECB',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.4' => 'rc4',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.5' => 'rc4WithMAC',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.6' => 'DESX-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.7' => 'DES-EDE3-CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.8' => 'RC5CBC',
    '1.2.840.113549.3.9' => 'RC5-CBCPad',
    '1.2.840.113556.4.3' => 'microsoftExcel',
    '1.2.840.113556.4.4' => 'titledWithOID',
    '1.2.840.113556.4.5' => 'microsoftPowerPoint',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84' => 'x9-84',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.0' => 'x9-84-Module',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.0.1' => 'x9-84-Biometrics',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.0.2' => 'x9-84-CMS',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.0.3' => 'x9-84-Identifiers',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1' => 'biometric',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.0' => 'id-unknown-Type',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.1' => 'id-body-Odor',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.10' => 'id-palm',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.11' => 'id-retina',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.12' => 'id-signature',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.13' => 'id-speech-Pattern',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.14' => 'id-thermal-Image',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.15' => 'id-vein-Pattern',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.16' => 'id-thermal-Face-Image',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.17' => 'id-thermal-Hand-Image',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.18' => 'id-lip-Movement',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.19' => 'id-gait',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.2' => 'id-dna',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.3' => 'id-ear-Shape',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.4' => 'id-facial-Features',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.5' => 'id-finger-Image',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.6' => 'id-finger-Geometry',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.7' => 'id-hand-Geometry',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.8' => 'id-iris-Features',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.1.9' => 'id-keystroke-Dynamics',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.2' => 'processing-algorithm',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.3' => 'matching-method',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4' => 'format-Owner',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.0' => 'cbeff-Owner',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1' => 'ibia-Owner',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.1' => 'id-ibia-SAFLINK',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.10' => 'id-ibia-SecuGen',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.11' => 'id-ibia-PreciseBiometric',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.12' => 'id-ibia-Identix',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.13' => 'id-ibia-DERMALOG',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.14' => 'id-ibia-LOGICO',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.15' => 'id-ibia-NIST',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.16' => 'id-ibia-A3Vision',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.17' => 'id-ibia-NEC',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.18' => 'id-ibia-STMicroelectronics',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.2' => 'id-ibia-Bioscrypt',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.3' => 'id-ibia-Visionics',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.4' => 'id-ibia-InfineonTechnologiesAG',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.5' => 'id-ibia-IridianTechnologies',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.6' => 'id-ibia-Veridicom',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.7' => 'id-ibia-CyberSIGN',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.8' => 'id-ibia-eCryp.',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.1.9' => 'id-ibia-FingerprintCardsAB',
    '1.3.133.16.840.9.84.4.2' => 'x9-Owner',
    '1.3.14.2.26.5' => 'sha',
    '1.3.14.3.2.1.1' => 'rsa',
    '1.3.14.3.2.10' => 'desMAC',
    '1.3.14.3.2.11' => 'rsaSignature',
    '1.3.14.3.2.12' => 'dsa',
    '1.3.14.3.2.13' => 'dsaWithSHA',
    '1.3.14.3.2.14' => 'mdc2WithRSASignature',
    '1.3.14.3.2.15' => 'shaWithRSASignature',
    '1.3.14.3.2.16' => 'dhWithCommonModulus',
    '1.3.14.3.2.17' => 'desEDE',
    '1.3.14.3.2.18' => 'sha',
    '1.3.14.3.2.19' => 'mdc-2',
    '1.3.14.3.2.2' => 'md4WitRSA',
    '1.3.14.3.2.2.1' => 'sqmod-N',
    '1.3.14.3.2.20' => 'dsaCommon',
    '1.3.14.3.2.21' => 'dsaCommonWithSHA',
    '1.3.14.3.2.22' => 'rsaKeyTransport',
    '1.3.14.3.2.23' => 'keyed-hash-seal',
    '1.3.14.3.2.24' => 'md2WithRSASignature',
    '1.3.14.3.2.25' => 'md5WithRSASignature',
    '1.3.14.3.2.26' => 'sha1',
    '1.3.14.3.2.27' => 'dsaWithSHA1',
    '1.3.14.3.2.28' => 'dsaWithCommonSHA1',
    '1.3.14.3.2.29' => 'sha-1WithRSAEncryption',
    '1.3.14.3.2.3' => 'md5WithRSA',
    '1.3.14.3.2.3.1' => 'sqmod-NwithRSA',
    '1.3.14.3.2.4' => 'md4WithRSAEncryption',
    '1.3.14.3.2.6' => 'desECB',
    '1.3.14.3.2.7' => 'desCBC',
    '1.3.14.3.2.8' => 'desOFB',
    '1.3.14.3.2.9' => 'desCFB',
    '1.3.14.3.3.1' => 'simple-strong-auth-mechanism',
    '1.3.14.7.2.1.1' => 'ElGamal',
    '1.3.14.7.2.3.1' => 'md2WithRSA',
    '1.3.14.7.2.3.2' => 'md2WithElGamal',
    '1.3.36.3' => 'algorithm',
    '1.3.36.3.1' => 'encryptionAlgorithm',
    '1.3.36.3.1.1' => 'des',
    '1.3.36.3.1.1.1.1' => 'desECBPad',
    '1.3.36.3.1.1.1.1.1' => 'desECBPadISO',
    '1.3.36.3.1.1.2.1' => 'desCBCPad',
    '1.3.36.3.1.1.2.1.1' => 'desCBCPadISO',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2' => 'idea',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.1' => 'ideaECB',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.1.1' => 'ideaECBPad',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.1.1.1' => 'ideaECBPadISO',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.2' => 'ideaCBC',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.2.1' => 'ideaCBCPad',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.2.1.1' => 'ideaCBCPadISO',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.3' => 'ideaOFB',
    '1.3.36.3.1.2.4' => 'ideaCFB',
    '1.3.36.3.1.3' => 'des-3',
    '1.3.36.3.1.3.1.1' => 'des-3ECBPad',
    '1.3.36.3.1.3.1.1.1' => 'des-3ECBPadISO',
    '1.3.36.3.1.3.2.1' => 'des-3CBCPad',
    '1.3.36.3.1.3.2.1.1' => 'des-3CBCPadISO',
    '1.3.36.3.2' => 'hashAlgorithm',
    '1.3.36.3.2.1' => 'ripemd160',
    '1.3.36.3.2.2' => 'ripemd128',
    '1.3.36.3.2.3' => 'ripemd256',
    '1.3.36.3.2.4' => 'mdc2singleLength',
    '1.3.36.3.2.5' => 'mdc2doubleLength',
    '1.3.36.3.3' => 'signatureAlgorithm',
    '1.3.36.3.3.1' => 'rsa',
    '1.3.36.3.3.1.1' => 'rsaMitSHA-1',
    '1.3.36.3.3.1.2' => 'rsaMitRIPEMD160',
    '1.3.36.3.3.2' => 'ellipticCurve',
    '1.3.36.3.4' => 'signatureScheme',
    '1.3.36.3.4.1' => 'iso9796-1',
    '1.3.36.3.4.2.1' => 'iso9796-2',
    '1.3.36.3.4.2.2' => 'iso9796-2rsa',
    '1.3.36.4' => 'attribute',
    '1.3.36.5' => 'policy',
    '1.3.36.6' => 'api',
    '1.3.36.6.1' => 'manufacturerSpecific',
    '1.3.36.6.2' => 'functionalitySpecific',
    '1.3.36.7' => 'api',
    '1.3.36.7.1' => 'keyAgreement',
    '1.3.36.7.2' => 'keyTransport',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.2428.10.1.1' => 'UNINETT policyIdentifier',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.2712.10' => 'ICE-TEL policyIdentifier',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.3029.32.1' => 'cryptlibEnvelope',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.3029.32.2' => 'cryptlibPrivateKey',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311' => 'Microsoft OID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10' => 'Crypto 2.0',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.1' => 'certTrustList',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.1.1' => 'szOID_SORTED_CTL',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.10' => 'Microsoft CMC OIDs',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.10.1' => 'szOID_CMC_ADD_ATTRIBUTES',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11' => 'Microsoft certificate property OIDs',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11.1' => 'szOID_CERT_PROP_ID_PREFIX',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.12' => 'CryptUI',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.12.1' => 'szOID_ANY_APPLICATION_POLICY',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.2' => 'nextUpdateLocation',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.1' => 'certTrustListSigning',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.10' => 'szOID_KP_QUALIFIED_SUBORDINATION',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.11' => 'szOID_KP_KEY_RECOVERY',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.12' => 'szOID_KP_DOCUMENT_SIGNING',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.2' => 'timeStampSigning',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.3' => 'serverGatedCrypto',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.3.1' => 'szOID_SERIALIZED',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4' => 'encryptedFileSystem',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4.1' => 'szOID_EFS_RECOVERY',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.5' => 'szOID_WHQL_CRYPTO',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6' => 'szOID_NT5_CRYPTO',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.7' => 'szOID_OEM_WHQL_CRYPTO',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.8' => 'szOID_EMBEDDED_NT_CRYPTO',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.9' => 'szOID_ROOT_LIST_SIGNER',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.4.1' => 'yesnoTrustAttr',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.5.1' => 'szOID_DRM',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.5.2' => 'szOID_DRM_INDIVIDUALIZATION',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.6.1' => 'szOID_LICENSES',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.6.2' => 'szOID_LICENSE_SERVER',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.7' => 'szOID_MICROSOFT_RDN_PREFIX',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.7.1' => 'szOID_KEYID_RDN',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.8.1' => 'szOID_REMOVE_CERTIFICATE',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.9.1' => 'szOID_CROSS_CERT_DIST_POINTS',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12' => 'Catalog',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.1.1' => 'szOID_CATALOG_LIST',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.1.2' => 'szOID_CATALOG_LIST_MEMBER',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.2.1' => 'CAT_NAMEVALUE_OBJID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.2.2' => 'CAT_MEMBERINFO_OBJID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13' => 'Microsoft PKCS10 OIDs',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.1' => 'szOID_RENEWAL_CERTIFICATE',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.1' => 'szOID_ENROLLMENT_NAME_VALUE_PAIR',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.2' => 'szOID_ENROLLMENT_CSP_PROVIDER',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.3' => 'OS Version',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.15' => 'Microsoft Java',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.16' => 'Microsoft Outlook/Exchange',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.16.4' => 'Outlook Express',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17' => 'Microsoft PKCS12 attributes',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.1' => 'szOID_LOCAL_MACHINE_KEYSET',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18' => 'Microsoft Hydra',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.19' => 'Microsoft ISPU Test',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2' => 'Authenticode',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.10' => 'spcAgencyInfo',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.11' => 'spcStatementType',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.12' => 'spcSpOpusInfo',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.14' => 'certExtensions',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.15' => 'spcPelmageData',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.18' => 'SPC_RAW_FILE_DATA_OBJID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.19' => 'SPC_STRUCTURED_STORAGE_DATA_OBJID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.20' => 'spcLink',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.21' => 'individualCodeSigning',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.22' => 'commercialCodeSigning',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.25' => 'spcLink',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.26' => 'spcMinimalCriteriaInfo',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.27' => 'spcFinancialCriteriaInfo',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.28' => 'spcLink',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.29' => 'SPC_HASH_INFO_OBJID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.30' => 'SPC_SIPINFO_OBJID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.4' => 'spcIndirectDataContext',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2' => 'CTL for Software Publishers Trusted CAs',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.1' => 'szOID_TRUSTED_CODESIGNING_CA_LIST',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.2' => 'szOID_TRUSTED_CLIENT_AUTH_CA_LIST',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.3' => 'szOID_TRUSTED_SERVER_AUTH_CA_LIST',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20' => 'Microsoft Enrollment Infrastructure',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.1' => 'szOID_AUTO_ENROLL_CTL_USAGE',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2' => 'szOID_ENROLL_CERTTYPE_EXTENSION',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.1' => 'szOID_ENROLLMENT_AGENT',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2' => 'szOID_KP_SMARTCARD_LOGON',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3' => 'szOID_NT_PRINCIPAL_NAME',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.3' => 'szOID_CERT_MANIFOLD',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21' => 'Microsoft CertSrv Infrastructure',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.1' => 'szOID_CERTSRV_CA_VERSION',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.20' => 'Client Information',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.25' => 'Microsoft Directory Service',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.25.1' => 'szOID_NTDS_REPLICATION',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3' => 'Time Stamping',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.2.1' => 'SPC_TIME_STAMP_REQUEST_OBJID',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.30' => 'IIS',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.31' => 'Windows updates and service packs',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.31.1' => 'szOID_PRODUCT_UPDATE',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.4' => 'Permissions',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.40' => 'Fonts',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.41' => 'Microsoft Licensing and Registration',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.42' => 'Microsoft Corporate PKI (ITG)',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88' => 'CAPICOM',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.1' => 'szOID_CAPICOM_VERSION',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2' => 'szOID_CAPICOM_ATTRIBUTE',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.1' => 'szOID_CAPICOM_DOCUMENT_NAME',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.2' => 'szOID_CAPICOM_DOCUMENT_DESCRIPTION',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.3' => 'szOID_CAPICOM_ENCRYPTED_DATA',
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.3.1' => 'szOID_CAPICOM_ENCRYPTED_CONTENT',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7' => 'pkix',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1' => 'privateExtension',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1' => 'authorityInfoAccess',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.12.2' => 'CMC Data',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2' => 'policyQualifierIds',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1' => 'cps',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.2' => 'unotice',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3' => 'keyPurpose',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1' => 'serverAuth',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2' => 'clientAuth',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3' => 'codeSigning',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4' => 'emailProtection',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.5' => 'ipsecEndSystem',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.6' => 'ipsecTunnel',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.7' => 'ipsecUser',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8' => 'timeStamping',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.4' => 'cmpInformationTypes',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.4.1' => 'caProtEncCert',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.4.2' => 'signKeyPairTypes',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.4.3' => 'encKeyPairTypes',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.4.4' => 'preferredSymmAlg',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.4.5' => 'caKeyUpdateInfo',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.4.6' => 'currentCRL',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1' => 'ocsp',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2' => 'caIssuers',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.8.1.1' => 'HMAC-MD5',
    '1.3.6.1.5.5.8.1.2' => 'HMAC-SHA',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.1' => 'sdnsSignatureAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.10' => 'mosaicKeyManagementAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.11' => 'sdnsKMandSigAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.12' => 'mosaicKMandSigAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.13' => 'SuiteASignatureAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.14' => 'SuiteAConfidentialityAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.15' => 'SuiteAIntegrityAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.16' => 'SuiteATokenProtectionAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.17' => 'SuiteAKeyManagementAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.18' => 'SuiteAKMandSigAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.19' => 'mosaicUpdatedSigAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.2' => 'mosaicSignatureAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.20' => 'mosaicKMandUpdSigAlgorithms',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.21' => 'mosaicUpdatedIntegAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.22' => 'mosaicKeyEncryptionAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.3' => 'sdnsConfidentialityAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.4' => 'mosaicConfidentialityAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.5' => 'sdnsIntegrityAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.6' => 'mosaicIntegrityAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.7' => 'sdnsTokenProtectionAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.8' => 'mosaicTokenProtectionAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.101.2.1.1.9' => 'sdnsKeyManagementAlgorithm',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1' => 'cert-extension',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.1' => 'netscape-cert-type',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.10' => 'EntityLogo',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.11' => 'UserPicture',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.12' => 'netscape-ssl-server-name',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.13' => 'netscape-comment',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.2' => 'netscape-base-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.3' => 'netscape-revocation-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.4' => 'netscape-ca-revocation-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.7' => 'netscape-cert-renewal-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.8' => 'netscape-ca-policy-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.1.9' => 'HomePage-url',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.2' => 'data-type',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.2.1' => 'GIF',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.2.2' => 'JPEG',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.2.3' => 'URL',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.2.4' => 'HTML',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.2.5' => 'netscape-cert-sequence',
    '2.16.840.1.113730.2.6' => 'netscape-cert-url',
```

Answer (score 1):

There does seem to be a web resource which collates it form as many registering authorities as possible.

This is:-   http://www.oid-info.com

From their webpage:

> The OID Resolution System (ORS) was developed from 2004 onwards, and allows an application to obtain (online) application-specific information related to any node identified by an OID.
>
> The ORS enables any one of the OID nodes to be mapped into DNS name zone files, and information about it can be obtained by a DNS look-up for further application processing. The system was initially designed to support RFID tag activity, but also has applications in many other application areas.

Comment: Nice! Paraphrasing their information, this seems to be a sort-of-wiki where volunteers have been collecting OIDs for the past three decades or so and uploading to that platform. It's reasonably complete; I managed to catch a few of the more obscure OIDs (even if they're in the RFCs!). It's also *very* interesting that they allow DNS queries for OID resolution! Makes a lot of sense — best distributed API ever :)