# What is CN & 0 & 0U in TLS & SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.3

I wonted to create my own **self-Signed-Certificate** of a project.

For that I have flowed this [tutorial](https://devopscube.com/create-self-signed-certificates-openssl/)

**So according to that**

I have generated my **own certificate authority** with **openssl** with this command

```
openssl req -x509 \
        -sha256 -days 356 \
        -nodes \
        -newkey rsa:2048 \
        -subj "/CN=demo.mlopshub.com/C=US/L=San Fransisco" \
        -keyout rootCA.key -out rootCA.crt
```

Then to create my **self-Signed-Certificate** I created a **key** with this command

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
```

Then I create a **Signing Request Configuration** file

```
cat > csr.conf <<EOF
 [ req ]
 default_bits = 2048
 prompt = no
 default_md = sha256
 req_extensions = req_ext
 distinguished_name = dn

 [ dn ]
 C = US
 ST = California
 L = San Fransisco
 O = MLopsHub
 OU = MlopsHub Dev
 CN = demo.mlopshub.com

 [ req_ext ]
 subjectAltName = @alt_names

 [ alt_names ]
 DNS.1 = demo.mlopshub.com
 DNS.2 = www.demo.mlopshub.com
 IP.1 = 192.168.1.5
 IP.2 = 192.168.1.6

 EOF
```

Then I created **Certificate Signing Request (CSR)** with the key

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config csr.conf
```

Then I created **Create a external file**

```
cat > cert.conf <<EOF

  authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
  basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
  keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
  subjectAltName = @alt_names

  [alt_names]
  DNS.1 = demo.mlopshub.com

  EOF
```

Then **Generate SSL certificate With self signed CA**

```
openssl x509 -req \
-in server.csr \
-CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key \
-CAcreateserial -out server.crt \
-days 365 \
-sha256 -extfile cert.conf
```

What I am thinking is what should I put in **O && OU** in my **csr.conf**.
And what is **CN**. And why should  I put **two** **DNS** and **two** **IPS**.

Comment: This is not programming or development and now off-topic, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464129/certificate-subject-x-509 from a decade ago when it was on. In fact any extensions in the file used for `req -new` (your `csr.conf`) are ignored by `openssl x509 -req -CA*` (there are numerous Qs/As about this) and you might as well omit them; you _should_ put in the file used for `x509 -req` (your `cert.conf`) all DNS names and/or IPs you wish to use in requests IF you are using HTTPS which you didn't say. PS it's letter O not 0 (zero).